# SQL Query/Procedure with user input to view all persons meeting a criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an SQL database which I need to create a procedure or query that is linked to a web front end where the user can type in a value which will be in one of the columns of the database. The user types in the value, submits the command (just normal text entry in a textbox in the website), a query is ran in the background to view all persons who have this value in the column under their entry.
User entry to determine the outcome for a view of specific people.

SQL Side I have currently but not certain it is correct, works but not as intended!

I have a table with people in it and a model of interest value column.
Each model of interest is just a number 1-7 which relates to a product range in another table. So 1 = a Corsa, 2 = Astra, 3 = Vectra etc.
So in the persons table, they will have purely a 1 or a 2 etc. Now I need it to be linked to the model table so if it sees 1 it looks for Corsa rather than the number 1.

A user types in the frontend, select all users interested in a Corsa, it will look up the word corsa and match it to the value 1, then search for 1 in the model of interest column in the person table.

So far I have the following query. Any suggestions as I'm stumped for today. Will try again tomorrow.

```
SELECT TOP 100 [ld_idno]
      ,[ld_company]
      ,[ld_decisionmaker]
      ,[ld_decisionmaker_workphone]
      ,[ld_decisionmaker_mobile]
      ,[ld_decisionmaker_email]
      ,[ld_discussion_model]
  FROM [FMLive204].[dbo].[tblLeads]
SELECT  a.po_word
FROM    dbo.tblPopulation a
            INNER JOIN  dbo.tblLeads b
                ON ld_discussion_model = po_idno
                WHERE [po_word]='Corsa'
```

SELECT TOP 100 Unique Records
    company name
    customer name
    customer workphone]
    customer mobile]
    customer email]
    [ld_discussion_model] Model of interest = 1
    FROM [FMLive204].[dbo].[tblLeads]
    SELECT  a.po_word
    FROM    dbo.tblPopulation a (table a)
    INNER JOIN  dbo.tblLeads b (table b)
    ON ld_discussion_model = po_idno (if the model of interest 1 is the same as an entry in the other table, pick the value in the next columne (po_word)
    WHERE [po_word]='Corsa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel,

Below I've outlined the stored procedure which would require the userdata (e.g. Corsa entered from the website) and return all fields from tblpopulation where 'po_idno' is in the list matched against the tblLeads. Not having the tblpopulation definition I'm guessing for field name 'po_idno' is the field which has the value 1-7 in it.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_find_person] (@UserData varchar(6))
AS
BEGIN


 SELECT Top 100 * FROM [FMLive204].[dbo].tblpopulation
where po_idno in (SELECT po_idno FROM  dbo.tblLeads b
            JOIN   dbo.tblPopulation a
                ON ld_discussion_model = po_idno
                WHERE [po_word]=@UserData)
```

Once you create the procedure you'll have to execute it which more information can be found @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx

Comment: Thank you that's brilliant. Looks much better! I'm new and learning SQL day by the day so I'm no expert but aim to crack most of the things we use it for here at work. Just tried the procedure, executing it and I get the following error. **Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_find_person, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near ')'.**

Comment: Daniel, I'm glad I could help since I'm rather a newbie at SQL too. Please accept my answer so that you'll get more answers if you ask other questions.

Comment: Ok I have the following now, and not really sure how i'd get round this. Useless I know...

But please see above...

Comment: Since I don't have your table structure, what kind of troubleshooting steps have you taken to resolve the issue?